# Cross Entropy Loss in Flux.jl - Julia

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I want to setup my model to use cross entropy loss in Flux.jl. How can I do this and where would I pass the loss function itself?

Comment: Thanks ! There was a downvote (not mine) probably because currently the *question* does not *show* any research effort. I'd advise to state at the beginning "*This is a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), to share knowledge*". That would serve two purposes: 1) knowledgeable people do not start thinking about a solution while reading the question (By the way, the answer could be marked as accepted ?), and 2) users do not get the impression that this question *alone* would meet the standard desired for this site.

Comment: You can’t accept your own answer right away and I like leaving it open in case others come up with a better answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flux.jl provides a build in module with many common loss function via the `Flux.Losses` module which you can access by doing `using Flux.Losses`. There is a built in cross entropy loss function in the module which can be used as follows:

```
julia> y_label = Flux.onehotbatch([0, 1, 2, 1, 0], 0:2)
3×5 Flux.OneHotArray{3,2,Vector{UInt32}}:
 1  0  0  0  1
 0  1  0  1  0
 0  0  1  0  0

julia> y_model = softmax(reshape(-7:7, 3, 5) .* 1f0)
3×5 Matrix{Float32}:
 0.0900306  0.0900306  0.0900306  0.0900306  0.0900306
 0.244728   0.244728   0.244728   0.244728   0.244728
 0.665241   0.665241   0.665241   0.665241   0.665241

julia> sum(y_model; dims=1)
1×5 Matrix{Float32}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> Flux.crossentropy(y_model, y_label)
1.6076053f0
```

You can find the complete `Flux.crossentropy` function definition here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/losses/#Flux.Losses.crossentropy

After you define the loss function, you can pass it to the built in train function: `Flux.train!(loss, params(model), data, opt)` or use it in your custom training loop.